# Awk: Words frequency from one text file, how to ouput into myFile.txt?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, frequency-analysis, word-frequency

**Given a .txt files** with space separated words such as:

```
But where is Esope the holly Bastard
But where is
```

And **the Awk function** :

```
cat /pathway/to/your/file.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2"@"$1}'
```

I get the **following output** in my console :

```
1 Bastard
1 Esope
1 holly
1 the
2 But
2 is
2 where
```

**How to get into printed into myFile.txt ?**
I actually have 300.000 lines and near 2 millions words. Better to output the result into a file.

---

EDIT: Used answer (by @Sudo_O):

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' RS=" |\n" myfile.txt | sort > myfileout.txt
```

Comment: Why can't you pipe the output from your console to a file?  You've done all the hard work.

Comment: I'am TOTALLY new to Awk / console scripts. I copied-pasted this code, understand it, but that's my very first script.

Comment: @Hugolpz it's a pretty inefficient method, take a look a my answer. You should let `awk` the whole job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pipeline isn't very efficient you should do the whole thing in `awk` instead:

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' RS=" |\n" file > myfile
```

If you want the output in sorted order:

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' RS=" |\n" file | sort > myfile
```

---

The actual output given by your pipeline is:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2"@"$1}'
Bastard@1
But@2
Esope@1
holly@1
is@2
the@1
where@2
```

Note: using `cat` is useless here we can just redirect the input with `<`. The `awk` script doesn't make sense either, it's just reversing the order of the words and words frequency and separating them with an `@`. If we drop the `awk` script the output is closer to the desired output *(notice the preceding spacing however and it's unsorted)*:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file | sort | uniq -c 
      1 Bastard
      2 But
      1 Esope
      1 holly
      2 is
      1 the
      2 where
```

We could `sort` again a remove the leading spaces with `sed`:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file | sort | uniq -c | sort | sed 's/^\s*//'
1 Bastard
1 Esope
1 holly
1 the
2 But
2 is
2 where
```

But like I mention at the start let `awk` handle it:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' RS=" |\n" file | sort
1 Bastard
1 Esope
1 holly
1 the
2 But
2 is
2 where
```

Comment: the '> myfile' disapear of your codes, could you put it back ?
You may also want to answer to [this associated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599781/awk-what-wrong-with-cjk-characters-korean) with [a link to here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598935/awk-how-to-output-result-into-myfile-txt-words-frequency/15600106?#15600106) since your final awk code works for it too !

Comment: The `> myfile` redirects output from `stdout` to the file `myfile` that means you don't see the output in the terminal instead it is written to disk and you see nothing *(assuming nothing is written to stderr)*. I don't use redirection after the first two `awk` scripts as I want the output to printed so you can see what is happening. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Can be complementary with @edouard_lopez **Tips**: "use *tee* which allow to redirect to a file AND still see the output"

Comment: I had to use `sort` with the `--numeric-sort` flag so that the word counts were sorted by numeric value rather than string representation.

Answer (score 2):

Just redirect output to a file.

```
cat /pathway/to/your/file.txt % tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | \
awk '{print $2"@"$1}' > myFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [shell redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) :

```
 echo "test" > overwrite-file.txt
 echo "test" >> append-to-file.txt
```

#### Tips

A useful command is `tee` which allow to redirect to a file and still see the output :

```
echo "test" | tee overwrite-file.txt
echo "test" | tee -a append-file.txt
```

#### Sorting and locale

I see you are working with asian script, you need to be need to be careful with the locale use by your system, as the resulting sort might not be what you expect :

> *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.

And have a look at the output of :

```
locale
```