# Awk: What wrong with CJK characters? #Korean

Tags: awk, cjk, word-frequency

**Given a .txt files** with space-separated words such as:

```
But where is Esope the holly Bastard
But where is 생 지 옥 이 군
지 옥 이
지 옥
지
我 是 你 的 爸 爸 ！
爸 爸 ！ ！ ！
你 不 會 的 ！
```

And **the Awk function** :

```
cat /pathway/to/your/file.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2" "$1}'
```

I get the **following output** in my console which is **invalid for korean words** (valid for english and Chinese space-separated words)

```
생 16
Bastard 1
But 2
Esope 1
holly 1
is 2
the 1
where 2
不 1
你 2
我 1
是 1
會 1
爸 4
的 2
```

**How to get it works for korean words ?**
Note: I actually have 300.000 lines and near 2 millions words.

---

EDIT: Used answer:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' RS=" |\n" myfile.txt | sort > myfileout.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `awk` script can handle this easily and will be far more efficient than your current pipeline:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' RS=" |\n" file 
옥 3
Bastard 1
！ 5
爸 4
군 1
지 4
But 2
會 1
你 2
the 1
是 1
不 1
이 2
Esope 1
的 2
holly 1
where 2
생 1
我 1
is 2
```

If you want to store the results into another file you can use redirection like:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' RS=" |\n" file > outfile
```

Comment: Very simply : Awesome! Thanks you.

Comment: This answer is [explained in detals there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598935/awk-how-to-output-result-into-myfile-txt-words-frequency/15600106?#15600106)