# Word frequency table - different results

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to get a frequency table of words in linux, using shell commands:

I'd like to know how many times "?xml" occurs in the file.

so option1 is `grep, sort, unique` and :

```
 cat allWords.txt | grep  "<?xml"  | sort | uniq -c  
      1 Data=<?xml
     12 'http://www.cs.caltech.edu/~adam/schemas/bCard'><bCard><?xml
      1 <?xml?>
   1099 <?xml
      4 '<?xml'
      3 '<?xml
```

which is **correct**.

option 2 is to use faster `awk`: [Awk: Words frequency from one text file, how to ouput into myFile.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598935/awk-words-frequency-from-one-text-file-how-to-ouput-into-myfile-txt)

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' allWords.txt  | grep "<?xml"
554 <?xml
6 'http://www.cs.caltech.edu/~adam/schemas/bCard'><bCard><?xml
3 '<?xml'
```

which incorrect for some words, but correct for others. awk could be just find for me if I could get it to work right.

So why there's a difference?

**EDIT**

I change from dows to unix:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' allWords.txt
```

and now:

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(k in a)print a[k],k}' allWords.txt  | grep "<?xml"
611 <?xml
5 'http://www.cs.caltech.edu/~adam/schemas/bCard'><bCard><?xml
3 '<?xml'
1 Data=<?xml
```

Also, the file appears to contain unicode strings.

Comment: You don't sort in awk, so why would you in bash ?  Also doing `grep "<?xml" allWords.txt ...` will save you a pipe step.  That being said, I can't help you with the awk script itself.

Comment: @tgo `unique -c` will not work if I won't use sort

Comment: If think the `RS=' |\n'`  might be the key. Using that, the original lines found by `grep` don't match the same lines found by `awk`. For instance, the following line `<xml>a b c<?xml><xml>cde<?xml>` will be splitted in three lines by `awk`, detecting TWO strings `<?xml` (increases twice the counter `a[$1]++)`, but `grep` instead will find just one line.

Comment: Check the lines of the line end with  the UNIX end-of-line character (`LF`), not the Windows/MS-DOS (`CR+LF`) one

Comment: Be in mind that the numbers reported by `grep+sort+uniq` means numbers of lines with the `same contents`; the following line `<?xml <?xml` will be reported by `grep+sort+uniq` as ONE, but `awk` instead will increase TWICE the counter (`a[$1]++`). You should check both attempts to be sure they will run the same way to print the same values.

Comment: Could you test with only the lines starting with `'<?xml'`? Awk reports 3, uniq reports 4. Who is right? Will the difference remain with a simplified file?

Comment: Without representative input, I don't think anybody can guess precisely what's going on or what we should be expecting.

Comment: @tripleee -> It's more than 0.5GB - what should I do?

Comment: "Representative" means show us a few lines for which the methods give different results.

Comment: Though based on the current information I guess @JDamian probably already had the answer.

Comment: @tripleee each word is in a separate line

Comment: @tripleee likes representive input. I suggested input with only the lines starting with `'<?xml'`. Using `grep "'<?xml'" allWords.txt > someWords.txt` should make a small input file where uniq and awk disagree.

Comment: Note that your question "how many times `?xml` appaers in the file" is different from the answer you qualified as correct, namely `grep  "<?xml"  | sort | uniq -c` (even the string is different). So what do you want to do ? Find `?xml`, `<?xml`, find the number of lines containing `?xml` (or `<?xml`), ... ? As @Jdamian reported, the solutions differs and would not give the same answers.